# Spring Boot Groovy Templates Not Adding _csrf to model

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a very simple Spring Boot Application which consists of a main Application.java (with the default main method), a MainController (which has one requestMapping to /login), and a SecurityConfig (with mainly default values).

My problem is with the _csrf support in Groovy Templates. Everything works fine with FreeMarker, but when I switch to GroovyTemplates the _csrf param does not get put into the model.

Is there a bug in the Groovy Templates, something manually I have to do to grab the token, or is there some configuration step I'm missing (although I don't know why it would work for FreeMarker) ?

**UPDATE:**

I printed this.properties (HashMap) on the login.tpl (Groovy Template) :

```
{class=class login, out=java.io.BufferedWriter@5e2aead3, model={error=Optional.empty, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.error=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, spring=org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@1d99fb33, springMacroRequestContext=org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@7fcc5c78}}
```

The model key in the properties map includes the parameters

I added error in the Controller action using the:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
    return new ModelAndView("views/login", "error", error);
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Spring security adds the token, if you want it in your form you will have to add it yourself.

Comment: My problem is that the spring security documentation only references _csrf as already included in the model (which seems to be the way it works when using Thymeleaf or FreeMarker templates), however when using Groovy Templates (traversing all properties; this.properties.each { } , there is no _csrf attribute in the model).  Is there a way to generate the _csrf token in the controller and manually include it in the module? If so, where is the documentation on that?

Comment: No as it isn't a property but a request attribute. Not sure what `this.properties` in a Groovy Template revers to. When using Thymeleaf or Freemarker the respective `IDialect` and tag library known what to do with that attribute. I highly doubt that that is the case for the Groovy Templates. But I'm sure that you have a way of printing the request attributes.

Comment: I've updated the question with the controller source, this.properties print out, and an explanation of the request attributes specified in the model key of this.properties .

Comment: But what I doubt is that `this.properties` is referring to request attributes.

Comment: try adding `spring.groovy.template.exposeRequestAttributes=true` to the `application.properties`.

Comment: I get:  org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'exposeRequestAttributes' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateProperties]

Comment: A shoot. I checked the wrong superclass. Which makes me wonder why the configuration class doesn't extend the other class. Let me create [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3365) for that.  The properties in the template aren't request attributes, setting that property would add the attributes to the map of properties for the template. What you can do instead is create a `BeanPostProcessor` which checks if the incoming bean is the `GroovyMarkupViewResolver` and set the `exposeRequestAttributes` to `true`. That way you should have the `_csfr` attribute available.

Comment: Ok, excellent! I set the exposeRequestAttributes to true with a BeanPostProcessor and I do have all of the Request Attributes now when I print this.properties (including _csrf).  However, the value of _csrf is SaveOnAccessCsrfToken which is causing an exception on my login form: "Cannot create a session after the response has been committed"

Comment: I just did this in my Controller and it appears to work now, let me know if that seems like the correct way to handle the session creation for the login form. (If you write up "A shoot. I checked the wrong superclass. Which makes me wonder why the configuration class doesn't extend ..." I can accept that as the answer. 

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam Optional<String> error, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
  session = request.getSession(true);
  return new ModelAndView("views/login",  "error", error);
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81995/discussion-between-brandon-wagner-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Are you running in a stateless environment?

Comment: No, not running in a stateless environment.

Comment: Instead of exposing the request attributes you can also try the interceptor approach from my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `GroovyMarkupView` and the `GroovyMarkupViewResolver` the properties of the view only contain properties available in the model (and some added for Groovy).

To include the request attributes set the `exposeRequestAttributes` property of the `GroovyMarkupViewResolver` to `true`. Ideally this is done by setting the following property in the `application.properties`.

```
spring.groovy.template.exposeRequestAttributes=true
```

However due to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3365) that currently isn't possible.

To work around it create a `BeanPostProcessor` which check if the incoming bean is a `GroovyMarkupViewResolver` (or `AbstractTemplateViewResolver` if you want a more general approach). If so set the `exposeRequestAttributes` to true.

```
public class TemplateViewResolverPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instance GroovyMarkupViewResolver) {
            ((GroovyMarkupViewResolver) bean).setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

After doing that the `CsfrToken` is available with the key `_csfr`, be aware that this is the actual `CsfrToken`.

Another solution is to create a `HandlerInterceptor` implement the `postHandle` method and add the `_csfr` property to the model. That way you can simply add the value of the token instead of the actual token itself. This will work with any view technology used.

```
public class CsrfAddingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler, ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) req.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName())
        if (token != null) {
            mav.addAttribute(token.getParameterName(), token.getToken());
        }
    }

}
```

Then add it as an interceptor and you will have the value available.

Answer (score 0):

So the hacked up way to handle this is to manually add the _csrf attribute to your model in your Controller.  For example:

```
model.addAttribute( "_csrf", request.getAttribute("_csrf") );
```

I wouldn't recommend that if you have lots of views on your server.  I'd suggest you follow one of the options from @M-Deinnum.  But, for quick testing this works.